# This script I wrote using async should take 10 seconds but instead takes 15. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

```py
import asyncio
import time

start = time.time()

class DMconvo:
    async def feature():
        print('hi')

    async def two():
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print('hi again')

async def test():
    await DMconvo.feature()
    await DMconvo.two() # should run in background and wait 5 seconds
    time.sleep(10) # should run while the previous script waits 5 seconds

asyncio.run(test())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start))
```

I think the code is running synchronously instead of asynchronously, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asyncio is still synchronous when calling await. This means that the code within `test()` is running sequentially with `DMconvo.two()` waiting 5 seconds and `time.sleep(10)` waiting 10 seconds. Totaling 15 seconds. You could use `asyncio.gather` to run co-routines concurrently eg.

```py
import asyncio
import time

start = time.time()

class DMconvo:
    async def feature():
        print('hi')

    async def two():
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print('hi again')


async def test():
    await asyncio.gather(
        DMconvo.feature(),
        DMconvo.two(),
        asyncio.sleep(10),
    )

asyncio.run(test())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start))
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> await DMconvo.two()
> time.sleep(10) # should run while the previous script waits 5 seconds
> ```

The assumption in this comment is incorrect.

`time.sleep(10)` is not executed until `DMconvo.two()` is finished.

Compared to synchronous execution, the advantage of using `await` is that the event loop can do other things while a task is waiting for I/O. But running a task in the background must still be done explicitly, for example by using [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

Furthermore, using `time.sleep` blocks the thread, in which also the `asyncio` event loop is running. To be able to sleep asynchronously, you need to use `asyncio.sleep`.

```
task = asyncio.create_task(DMconvo.two())
await asyncio.sleep(10)
await task
```

A more abstract and convenient approach to create and run multiple tasks concurrently is to use `asyncio.gather`, as shown in the [answer by ThisIsHowItIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63673182).

Answer (score -1):

Using await means "Program will wait there till this asynchronous function completes"

So,

```
await DMconvo.two()
```

Will wait for 5 secs.

Remove await from here and it will run this function in background.

Comment: Doing that returns RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'DMconvo.two' was never awaited